# JQ how to filter an output

Tags: linux, jq

I am still early in my scripting and coding and new to linux so please bear with me. I have the following command that works but just not as well as I hope it can.

```
jq -r '.User[]|{Username: .username, Full_name: .full_name, Superuser: .is_superuser, Active: .is_active}' lbc.prod.xxx.yyyy.zzzz.json > lbc.prod.xxx.yyyy.zzzz_Users.csv
```

This produces a CSV with all the users on it. I would really like to narrow this down to just superusers. I have tried the following but it failed

```
jq -r '.User[]|{Username: .username, Full_name: .full_name, Superuser: .is_superuser, Active: .is_active} | select(.is_superuser = "true")' lbc.prod.xxx.yyyy.zzzz.json > lbc.prod.xxx.yyyy.zzzz_SuperUsers.csv
```

That didn't work I also tried

```
jq -r '.User[]|{Username: .username, Full_name: .full_name, Superuser: .is_superuser{true}, Active: .is_active} ' lbc.prod.xxx.yyyy.zzzz.json > lbc.prod.xxx.yyyy.zzzz_SuperUsers.csv
```

but this produced errors and didn't run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter on the property `is_superuser`, you need to apply the `select` filter before transforming the object to a new structure:

```
.User[]
| select(.is_superuser)
| {Username: .username, Full_name: .full_name, Superuser: .is_superuser, Active: .is_active}
```

or, if you want to filter the newly created object structure:

```
.User[]
| {Username: .username, Full_name: .full_name, Superuser: .is_superuser, Active: .is_active}
| select(.Superuser)
```

Note that this will generate one JSON object per line, not CSV. If you want CSV output, you have to transform to an array and filter through `@csv`:

```
.User[]
| select(.is_superuser)
| [ .username, .full_name, .is_superuser, .is_active ]
| @csv
```

and if you need headers for your CSV file:

```
["Username", "Full name", "Superuser", "Active"],
(.User[]
| select(.is_superuser)
| [ .username, .full_name, .is_superuser, .is_active ])
| @csv
```

To get raw CSV output, run the with `--raw-output`/`-r` flag of jq:

```bash
$ cat input.json
{
  "User": [
    {
      "username": "name1",
      "full_name": "full_name",
      "is_superuser": true,
      "is_active": false
    },
    {
      "username": "name1",
      "full_name": "full_name",
      "is_superuser": false,
      "is_active": false
    },
    {
      "username": "name2",
      "full_name": "full_name",
      "is_superuser": true,
      "is_active": false
    },
    {
      "username": "name2",
      "full_name": "full_name",
      "is_superuser": false,
      "is_active": false
    }
  ]
}

$ jq -r '["Username", "Full name", "Superuser", "Active"],
(.User[]
| select(.is_superuser)
| [ .username, .full_name, .is_superuser, .is_active ])
| @csv' input.json > output.csv

$ cat output.csv
"Username","Full name","Superuser","Active"
"name1","full_name",true,false
"name2","full_name",true,false
```

Comment: HI knittl, Thank you for your response. Would this then be the correct command to run. 

I know I have gaps in my knowledge, Is this run as a single command or multiple?

.User[]
| select(.is_superuser)
| [ .username, .full_name, .is_superuser, .is_active ]
| @csv
and if you need headers for your CSV file:

["Username", "Full name", "Superuser", "Active"],
(.User[]
| select(.is_superuser)
| [ .username, .full_name, .is_superuser, .is_active ])
| "@"csv

Or do I place it in a script of some sort?

Comment: @asthmatic_weasel please see update in the answer, I have updated to show a full example

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer Knittl. That worked a treat. I really appreciate the help. I am now going to go and try and understand how it works. That has just saved me countless hours of effort.

Answer (score 0):

If in your source document `.is_superuser` is a boolean value, your `select` expression should read `select(.is_superuser == true)` (which can be abbreviated as `select(.is_superuser)`), and not `select(.is_superuser == "true")` (which makes a comparison to the literal string `"true"`).

```bash
.User[]
| select(.is_superuser)
| {Username: .username, Full_name: .full_name, Superuser: .is_superuser, Active: .is_active}
```

Also note that this does not create a CSV output. For that you'd need to generate an array for each record (e.g. `[.username, .full_name, .is_active]`), and apply `@csv` to it.

Comment: HI @pmf thank you for your answer. the original is a JSON file, and the superuser bit can either be true or false, so I think that is boolean. 

I am afraid that I don't follow what you mean about my output not being a CSV. It appears to create a CSV file that I can open and edit.